# My Variable is changing with class which is given as attribute to class

Tags: python, oop, object

I hava a class like

```
class Gate():
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.arr = lst
        self.fill()

    def get_arr(self):
        return self.arr

    def set_arr(self, index1, index2, value):
        self.arr[index1][index2] = value

    def fill(self):
        for i in range(len(self.arr)):
            self.arr[i].append(randrange(2))
```

I am creating class with "gate_list" attiribute. When creating new object it's adding 1's and 0's to object's list.

Until now every thing is okey. But with object's list also my "gate_list" variable is too changing.

```
Array = Gate(gate_list)
print(Array.get_arr())
print(gate_list)
```

Output

```
[['a', 1], ['b', 0], ['c', 0], ['z', 1], ['d', 1]]
[['a', 1], ['b', 0], ['c', 0], ['z', 1], ['d', 1]]
```

Where is my fault?

Comment: ... because they are *the same list*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.arr` has a reference to `gate_list`, which is passed to the constructor. Thus, any mutations of `self.arr` will also change `gate_list`. Instead, pass a copy of `gate_list` to `Gate`:

```
import copy

Array = Gate(copy.deepcopy(gate_list))
```